# What was Sora Iro no Tane advertising?

Tags: anime-history, studio-ghibli

One of the earliest Ghibli works, *Sora Iro no Tane* or *The Sky-Colored Seed*, was an advertisement broadcast on Japanese TV in 1992.

This little green dude seems to be the mascot of the product, he seems to be a pig:

[image]

I can't find any information about what it was advertising originally, and I can't draw a logical conclusion from the show.

Does anyone know what it was advertising? And how were the animation clips relevant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Sora Iro no Tane* was a TV spot made for [Nippon TV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nippon_TV#History_of_Nippon_Television) in 1993 to commemorate its 40th anniversary.

The creature is called "[Nandarou](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_films_by_Studio_Ghibli#Nandar.C5.8D)" (lit. What is it?) and designed by Hayao Miyazaki himself.

Comment: ah, so it was for the television broadcasters themselves!